# Add dashed lines to multiple plots created by seaborn's relplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to add dashed, diagonal lines where x = y to each plot in the figure shown below. They were created by seaborn's relplot, using the following code:

```
  p1 = sns.relplot(data=df2, x="H", y="CO2", col="Bias", hue="Met", col_wrap=5)
 (p1.set_axis_labels("$E_{ads}(*H)$", "$E_{ads}(*CO_2)$")
 .set_titles("Bias: {col_name} V vs SHE")
 .set(xlim=(-0.4, 2), ylim=(-0.4, 2)))
```

I tried adding the following lines of code, but it only adds the line I want to the last graph of the series:

```
xx = np.linspace(-1, 2, 100)
yy = xx 

p1 = sns.relplot(data=df2, x="H", y="CO2", col="Bias", hue="Met", col_wrap=5)
(p1.set_axis_labels("$E_{ads}(*H)$", "$E_{ads}(*CO_2)$")
.set_titles("Bias: {col_name} V vs SHE")
.set(xlim=(-0.4, 2), ylim=(-0.4, 2)))
plt.plot(xx, yy)
plt.show()
```

[Link to graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/telpw.png)

How do I add the line I would like to all plots in the figure? I am not sure if there is a way to do this with FacetGrid, but so far I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the various axes of the FacetGrid:

```
for ax in p1.axes.flat:
    ax.plot(xx,yy)
```